# Movilizer Barcode Screen Trigger Ok Event

Tags: barcode, scanning, mobility, movilizer

I'm using QType 23 2D barcode scan:

```
<question key="Q1_SCREEN_SCAN" type="23" title="Bitte scannen Barcode"
  <answer key="Q1_BARCODE_INPUT" attributeType="51" nextQuestionKey="Q2_EPSILON_RESULT"/>
...
```

With attributetype="51" that displays directly the scan screen.
Would it be possible to trigger the OK after scanning? instead of displaying the UID in the screen?
Thanks!
Regards,
Rami

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible attribute types you can use are:

- 51 allows you to scan or capture right away
- 52 triggers an OK event right after capturing or scanning
- 53 combines both of the above

so either attribute type 52 or 53 should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I found a full example for skipping the take in Capture screens at https://devtools.movilizer.com/confluence/display/DOC21/Skip+take+view+in+capture+screens.

It shows a Capture Barcode 1D screen, but it should also work with the 2D screen - just replace `type="22"` with `type="23"`.

So, in your case, it should look either like:

```
<!-- Skip only the take -->
<question key="Q1_SCREEN_SCAN" type="22" title="Bitte scannen Barcode"
  <answer key="Q1_BARCODE_INPUT" attributeType="52" nextQuestionKey="Q2_EPSILON_RESULT"/>
...
```

Or like:

```
<!-- Skip both default and take -->
<question key="Q1_SCREEN_SCAN" type="22" title="Bitte scannen Barcode"
  <answer key="Q1_BARCODE_INPUT" attributeType="53" nextQuestionKey="Q2_EPSILON_RESULT"/>
```